# Istanbul: Ignore __DEV__ else branch for coverage automatically

Tags: javascript, jestjs, istanbul

I have a block like this for DEV-only messages:

```js
if (__DEV__) {
  warn(...);
}
```

`__DEV__` is a Babel plugin (`babel-plugin-dev-expression`) which compiles to:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  warn(...);
}
```

Is there a way to **automatically** ignore the "else" branch for these blocks? Currently, manually writing this works:

```js
/* istanbul ignore else */
if (__DEV__) {
  warn(...);
}
```

I am using Jest as my test runner.

Comment: Note that it could be usefully to also test the else branch of those statements. A programmer might make the mistake of putting a function that has side effects inside the dev check. And this would cause it to fail in production. You aren't the first one to make that mistake.